# Make SKSpriteNode character move with SKSpriteNode platform

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm building a platform game that has an SKSpriteNode character who jumps onto moving platforms.

When the platform moves the character doesn't and it ends up falling off the platform. If I tap the move button the character moves along nicely, but I want the character to 'stick' to the platform as it moves.

I haven't posted code as the code is working as expected. I have a feeling its a property that I can set?

EDIT:

I have a solution - just not sure it's how people should do it so I'll post below and wait for feedback. It's long and complex and probably doesn't need to be.

When the user presses the left or right directional button I move the scene from GameScene.swift by:

```
    func moveGround(direction: String) {


    if direction == "left" {

        [snip...]
        // move the platforms
        self.enumerateChildNodesWithName("platform") {
            node, stop in

            if let foundNode = node as? PlatformSprite {
                node.position.x += Helper().kMovingDistance
            }

        }

        // move all other nodes
        self.enumerateChildNodesWithName("*") {
            node, stop in

            if let foundNode = node as? SKSpriteNode {
                node.position.x += Helper().kMovingDistance
            }

        }
        [snip...]

    } else if direction == "right" {

        [snip...]
        // move the platforms
        self.enumerateChildNodesWithName("platform") {
            node, stop in

            if let foundNode = node as? PlatformSprite {
                node.position.x -= Helper().kMovingDistance
            }

        }

        // move all other nodes
        self.enumerateChildNodesWithName("*") {
            node, stop in

            if let foundNode = node as? SKSpriteNode {
                node.position.x -= Helper().kMovingDistance
            }

        }
        [snip...]
    }
```

This moves the scene along nicely. Then when the character lands on top of a platform I initiate the platform movements using SKAction sequence AND initiate the scene movements by sending the reverse sequence to GameScene:

```
    func startMoving() {

    if !self.isMoving {

        [snip...]

        // get the platform actions and initiate the movements
        let actions = self.getMovements()
        let seq:SKAction = SKAction.sequence(actions)

        // move the platform
        self.runAction(seq, completion: { () -> Void in
            self.completedPlatformActions()
        })

        // get the reverse actions and initiate then on the scene / ground
        let reverseActions = self.getReverseMovements()
        let reverseSeq:SKAction = SKAction.sequence(reverseActions)

        delegate!.moveGroundWithPlatform(reverseSeq)

        self.isMoving = true

    }
}
```

Then I have a function for moving the ground with a platform and add a key to the runAction so I can stop just that action and not the platforms actions if the user ceases to be in contact with the platform:

```
   func moveGroundWithPlatform(seq: SKAction) {

    [snip...]

    self.enumerateChildNodesWithName("platform") {
        node, stop in

        if let foundNode = node as? PlatformSprite {
            node.runAction(seq, withKey: "groundSeq")
        }

    }
  [snip...]
  }
```

Then I stop moving the scene, but let the remaining actions of the platform continue using:

```
    func stopMovingGroundWithPlatform() {

    [snip...]
    self.enumerateChildNodesWithName("platform") {
        node, stop in

        if let foundNode = node as? PlatformSprite {
            node.removeActionForKey("groundSeq")
        }

    }
    [snip...]
}
```

Ugly I know - if others have suggestions about how better to do this I'd love to know :)

Comment: How are you moving the platform? Does your character have a physics body?

Comment: Hey - the character and the platforms have physics bodies. The platform is moved by taking currentLocation - kMovingDistance in the update function. When the platform moves right the character falls off the back, if the platform moves down the character 'bounces' all the way down.

Comment: as soon as the player touches a platform from above, the platform updates the player's position directly (by taking the difference between platform's current and previous positions) and afterwards the player adds his current velocity to it's own position so he can move while on the platform. It will be tricky to get this right as it depends on the update loop and correctly overriding physics behavior for a short time.

Comment: OK, thanks for the comments, I take it that the issue is more to do with how I am moving the platforms. It did feel like a bit of a hacky way to go about it. Thanks - appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want friction to move your character along with the platform, you will need to move the platform with a force, impulse, or by settings its velocity. I suspect it's easier to control a platform by settings its velocity. You can do that in the `update` method by

```
platform.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(dx,dy)
```

where `dx` and `dy` control the platforms speed in the x and y directions, respectively. You should also set the friction property of the platform's physics body as well.

Comment: Once I'm back at my MAC ill rework my approach to movement. I suspect that this is correct and will update / mark the answer aftewards. Thanks!

Comment: Question, I've got a working solution but I don't think its a great solution to mark as an answer. On SO should I put in how I got it working and mark that as the answer even if it's probably not the approach people should take? I'll update the question with some code to explain it and wait for comments on the best way to "Answer" this question.